# queuing theory for task

Tags: statistics

A gas station only has one pump for refueling the Pertamax type.
The arrival of Pertamax-fueled cars to the gas station follows the process
Poisson with an arrival rate of 15 cars / hour. However, when this pump is being used (there is
cars that are filling Pertamax), potential customers who come can move to
another gas station. In particular, if there are n cars at the gas station, chances are
potential customers who come, will move to another gas station is n / 3, for
n = 1, 2, 3. The time needed to serve a car is exponentially distributed
with an average of 4 minutes.

a. Draw the transition diagram and write the balance equations for the system
this queue.

b. Complete equilibrium equations to obtain the proportion of time
long term number of cars at the gas station.

c. Determine the expected waiting time of a car in this queue system.

Comment: Hello, @Yohanes Johan, welcome to MSE. Can you please add (in the question, not in a comment) what you have tried yourself and what you have found? That makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: Maybe start by looking at _standard results_ (b & c) for M/M/1 queue without restrictions on queue length. Then look at similar results for M/M/1/4 queue where there can be at most 4 cars in the system. Your answer should be btw thes two. // Notice that departure and _attempted_ arrival rates are the same.